# ASP.NET Core and EF Core 1.1 - Display data using Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have problem with my query. I want to display the result on a view.

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _Context.Employee
                              .FromSql("EXEC sp_GetLoanDetails")
                              .ToArrayAsync());
}
```

Here is my list of items I want to view:

```
public class StoredProcRow
{
    [Key]
    public int empID { get; set; }
    public string empFullName { get; set; }
    public double EducationalLoan { get; set; }
    public double PettyCash { get; set; }
    public double BusinessLoan { get; set; }
    public double ApplianceLoan { get; set; }
    public double EmergencyLoan { get; set; }
    public double AllPurposeLoan { get; set; }
    public double KAPUSOIILoan { get; set; }
    public double FiestaLoan { get; set; }
    public double SalaryLoan { get; set; }
    public double Pledge { get; set; }
    public double PagIbigLoan { get; set; }
    public double SSSLoan { get; set; }
    public double AllAroundLoan { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** These entities name are the same as entities on column name in `sp_GetLoanDetails`

Is this achievable right now on EF Core 1.1? Or do I need to go back to manual ADO.NET code?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s, Noted, Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While support for stored procedures isn’t completely there with Entity Framework Core [*yet*](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/245), you still can use `FromSql` to consume stored procedures with it.

In order to do that, the database context needs to know the entity you are mapping to from the stored procedure. Unfortunately, the only way to do that  right now is to actually define it as an entity in the database context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<StoredProcRow>(entity =>
    {
        // …
    });
}
```

Then, you can consume the stored procedure by running the `FromSql` method on a set for that entity:

```
public virtual IQueryable<StoredProcRow> GetLoanDetails()
{
    return Set<StoredProcRow>().FromSql("[sp_GetLoanDetails]").AsNoTracking();
}
```

Note that I’m using a `AsNoTracking` here to avoid the data context to track changes to entities that come from the stored procedure (since you don’t have a way to update them anyway). Also I’m using `Set<T>()` inside the method to avoid having to expose the type as a member on the database context since you cannot use the set without the stored procedure anyway.

Btw. you don’t need (not sure if that even works) `EXEC` in the sql statement you pass to `FromSql`. Just pass the stored procedure name and any arguments to it, e.g.:

```
Set<MyEntity>().FromSql("[SomeStoredProcedure]");
Set<MyEntity>().FromSql("[SProcWithOneArgument] @Arg = {0}");
Set<MyEntity>().FromSql("[SProcWithTwoArguments] @Arg1 = {0}, Arg2 = {1}");
```

Comment: Hi @poke, I have a little problem with the Set thing, do I need to download `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` or not? just a thought cuz something is wrong with the `Set<MyEntity>.FromSql`thingy...

Comment: Yes, in order to run `FromSql`, you need to have a dependency on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` since SQL is a relational thing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It fixed my issue right now... thanks for the solution.. saves my day.

Comment: @poke suppose my sp is returning a resultset of 3 columns like say RName, RId, OrgId.  i created a entity with these three properties.  like below public class resultcollection
    {
        public int Rid{ get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OrgId{ get; set; }
        public string RName{ get; set; }}  so how should the on ModelCreating look like if i need to call the sp.

Comment: @user1447718 You set up your entity for stored procedures just like any other entity (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/) for help). So you could even use the data annotations and then you just need a call `modelBuilder.Entity<ResultCollection>()`. Or you set up the model explicitly with the entity builder.

Comment: @Poke, it worked, but asked me to add a key to the entity.  anyway i can avoid that?

Comment: @user1447718 An entity is required to have a key in EF, but you can just choose any column/property of the entity for stored procedure entities. It does not have any effect when querying stored procedures.

Comment: @poke I see from your github comments you mentioned about your extensive experience in EF core. Would you mind sharing your ideas in a blog post - if time permits? thanks!

Comment: @blogs4t Is there a particular topic that you would want to be covered?

Comment: @poke nope. not any specific topic in mind at this time. Was looking for details in general - overall. of course if you have the time to blog. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From NuGet add System.Data.Common and System.Data.SqlClient. These allow ADO.NET commands to be run i.e. a stored procedure.

https://forums.asp.net/post/6061777.aspx