# How to call stored procedures using NET core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

just a newbie to .NET Core.  am using EF Core 1.1.  Am trying to call a SP which generates a complex resultset.  Meaning, the sp combines two-three tables and returns one combined result set.  in such cases, how to i call the SP.

i did some googling and see that there are some example like below
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/299/entity-framework-code-first-and-stored-procedures

using context.Database.SqlQuery.  but when i try, i don't get SQLQuery method of database.  i tried adding System.Data.Entity but it is not recognizing entity.

how should i proceed here?

Also can someone point me to a sample where there is clear seperation of concerns in terms of UI layer, Biz layer and DAL layer using EF core.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

see poke's response for the answer here
[ASP.NET Core and EF Core 1.1 - Diplay Data using Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087350/asp-net-core-and-ef-core-1-1-diplay-data-using-stored-procedure/43088033?noredirect=1#comment74396069_43088033)

that worked for me.