# How to retrieve summarized data from stored procedure with Entity Framework and .Net Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Using .Net Core 1.1 with Entity Framework with SQL database

I have a stored procedure which produces summarized data for things like Number of Orders, percentage change on previous month Total value of order in month and does this for the last 12 months.

This is used to graphing in client script and so doesn't have a model (and I don't want one as its not a real object), but I need to get the data into a view model to pass to the view for graphing on the client.

I am sure this is quite common requirement for summarized data but I'm not sure how to do this?

Edit: Question isn't quite the same as the one identified, I have used store procedures in .net core previously but the data mapped to real entities, where as I am returning summarized data here which doesn't have a model and want to do this in the most appropriate way.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core and EF Core 1.1 - Diplay Data using Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087350/asp-net-core-and-ef-core-1-1-diplay-data-using-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this in the end by creating a model with the following attributes:
[ComplexType]
[NotMapped]

This model contains properties to match the output of a stored procedure which I then call from my API